# How to align a background image to bottom of table cells in css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do something which I thought would be really simple..

I want to display a background image at the bottom of each table rows (or cells, whichever works best) but i'm getting some alignment issue.

The image always seems to align to the bottom of the cell content, but ignores any padding.

`border-origin:border-box` doesn't seem to have any influence on the result either.

Setting the background on the row itself (ie. the `tr` tag) produces the problem.

The background uses this syntax: `background:url('...') bottom left repeat-x;`

See the following screenshot of the results - i've added a semi transparent outline of the cell just to show the boundaries. The red dotted line is the background.

[image: Screenshot]

Here's a fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/bendog/gvtqwhw0/

(note: the fiddle CDNs to bootstrap, which i'm using for the project)

One would think this *should* be easy...

The problem occurs on my latest Chrome and Firefox on Mac (but haven't tried other browsers yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, well, do I feel a bit stupid!

The extra padding was blank space part of the image itself.

It works fine with a corrected image: [http://jsfiddle.net/bendog/gvtqwhw0/24/](http://jsfiddle.net/bendog/gvtqwhw0/25/)

Here's the updated image tag (apparently I can't post a link to jsfiddle without copying some code here too)

```
tr {
        background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) bottom left repeat-x;
    }
```

It became apparent when I used the same effect on a heading tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-position` adjust pixels wherever necessary

```
tr {
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) repeat-x;
    background-position:0% 104%;
}
```

**Working fiddle**

**http://jsfiddle.net/gvtqwhw0/23/**

Comment: i have updated the answer it is working in IE, Firefox and chrome. yes it uses hard-code position pixels.

Comment: Hard code pixels aren't practical, what if a row goes on two line?

Comment: check now, i have given values in percentage. it is working for any amount of lines. tested in IE, Firefox and chrome browsers in windows

Comment: Thanks for trying again. It doesn't work for me on Chrome on osx - the background image is simply not displayed.. It starts to appear at a 102% offset but still appears slightly off centred..

Comment: hmm.. sorry i dont have OSX.

Comment: Unfortunately this just shows this proposed fix is more of a hack around the issue than a solution for it. Thanks for trying though.